# Dropbox Datastore Observers on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

In the Tasks sample app for the Dropbox Datastore API ([found here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios)) the observers are set up and discarded in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`, respectively:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    __weak TasksController *slf = self;
    [self.accountManager addObserver:self block:^(DBAccount *account) {
        [slf setupTasks];
    }];

    [self setupTasks];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.accountManager removeObserver:self];
    if (_store) {
        [_store removeObserver:self];
    }
}
```

I am trying to set up global observers in a singleton class and am using `init` and `dealloc` since my class isn't a view controller.

```
//Custom init method to start up our Dropbox observer
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if(!self) return nil;

  [self startDatastore];

  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  [self.store addObserver:self block:^{
    [weakSelf getRemoteDropboxChanges];
  }];

  return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
  //Stop listening for Dropbox changes
  if(self.store) {
    [self.store removeObserver:self];
  }
}
```

...but alas, this doesn't work (the observer's block never fires). Can someone help me understand the difference?

Comment: Is `self.store` actually set to a non-nil value (presumably in your `startDatastore` method)? Are you sure your singleton doesn't get deallocated?

Comment: When I log the value of `self.store` it is not nil. You are correct, it gets set in `startDatastore`. How can I check if my singleton is getting deallocated or not?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `dealloc`.

Comment: I've been watching for it, and it looks like it doesn't get deallocated. That helps confirm a few things, thanks.